# Replace first column on csv file based on their value

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file structured like this:

```
01 - FOO_1,value2,value3,...
01 - FOO_1,value2,value3,...
07 - FOO_7,value2,value3,...
...
```

How do i change the first column so it keeps only the number and looks like this:

```
01,value2,value3,...
01,value2,value3,...
07,value2,value3,...
```

Comment: Will you please edit your post and show us what you have tried?

Comment: @fd0 Obviously nothing as it is incredibly simple and a basic look around this site would give them an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F, '{ $1=sprintf("%02d",$1) }1' OFS=',' file
```

Answer (score 1):

with sed:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3/g' file
```

Comment: almost worked but it actually separated the text from the number creating another column

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ [^,]*//' file
```

..........